# Read heart rate data from wear os 2 watch to android app on phone

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, google-fit, heartrate

I have a Fossil Q Explorist HR watch that runs on wear os 2 and have a moto g60 phone. The watch and phone are connected via the Wear OS app installed on phone. I need to write an application using Kotlin for my phone that will read the heart rate data that my watch records. How do I do that?

I have tried many samples that Google repo had, but the communication between the watch and phone app isn't happening, so data isnt getting read on phone. I am expecting that the communication is established and the heart rate data on phone app I created and the watch data match